# Meteor.js icons are missing after update

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor, icons

I have updated my  meteor and now no icons are displayed - before the update all worked fine.

folder structure:

-public

--fonts

---tablet

---monitor

and I access the tablet icons with following code:

```
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Flaticon";
      src: url("fonts/tablet/Flaticon.eot");
      src: url("fonts/tablet/Flaticon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
           url("fonts/tablet/Flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
           url("fonts/tablet/Flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
           url("fonts/tablet/Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("fonts/tablet/Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  }
}

[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {
  font-family: Flaticon;
        font-size: 20px;
font-style: normal;
/*margin-left: 20px;*/
}

.flaticon-clock:before { content: "\f100";font-size: 60px; }
.flaticon-clock-circular-outline:before { content: "\f101"; }
.flaticon-cooking-stove-with-heat:before { content: "\f103"; font-size: 60px; color:white;}
.flaticon-one-finger-click-black-hand-symbol:before { content: "\f104"; font-size: 60px;  color:white;}

/*Pfanne blau*/
.flaticon-closed-pan-blue-white:before { content: "\f102"; color:blue; font-size: 140px;padding:0px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;border:1px solid #e0e0e0;}
.flaticon-closed-pan-white-blue:before { content: "\f102"; color:white; background-color:blue; font-size: 140px;padding:0px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;border:1px solid #e0e0e0;}

/*Topf gelb*/
.flaticon-saucepan-yellow-white:before { content: "\f105"; color:yellow; font-size: 120px; padding:10px; border:1px solid #e0e0e0;}
.flaticon-saucepan-white-yellow:before { content: "\f105"; color:white; font-size: 120px; padding:10px; background-color:yellow; }

/*Topf grün*/
.flaticon-saucepan-green-white:before { content: "\f105"; color:green; font-size: 120px;padding:10px; border:1px solid #e0e0e0;}
.flaticon-saucepan-white-green:before { content: "\f105"; color:white; background-color:green; font-size: 120px;padding:10px; border:1px solid #e0e0e0;}


/*.flaticon-saucepan-red:before { content: "\f105"; color:red; font-size: 120px;padding:10px; border:1px solid #e0e0e0;}*/
```

The strange thing is, that this code worked fine before the update but now no icons and images are displayed in my app.

Does anybody know the problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a leading slash ('/') to all of your icon paths.

`src: url("fonts/tablet/Flaticon.eot");`

maybe should be:

`src: url("/fonts/tablet/Flaticon.eot");`